# Querying a synonym (for a table using linked server) gives no data in return

Tags: functions, query, profiler, synonyms

I have a function which run in an application at a server. This server have a ODBC connection (user DSN) to the SQL server which is set to use windows authentication. 
The function is supposed to query a synonym on the SQL server and return a string.
The synonym is created using a linked server connection to a table in a database in the linked server.
The full script is:

```
Function OnClick()
Dim iPath as String
dim tQuery as string
Dim tActNo As String
Dim tCcaseID as string
Dim DBase, RS as Object
tActNo =  58333' eActNo.Title '241420 
debug   
DBase = CreateObject("DATABASE")
DBase.Connect("COMMON")  
 tQuery = "SELECT id FROM vContosoCcase WHERE Refno='" + tActNo + "' and Subcase=0"
IF (DBase.Query(RS, tQuery) = 0) 
   IF (RS.MoveNext = 0) 
     tCcaseID = RS.ID
   End if
   DeleteObject(RS)
ELSE
MessageBox(ErrorText(DBase.Query(RS, tQuery))
END IF
iPath= "http://www.contoso.com:44207/AppCaseMgmt/CaseList/ccaseId/" + tCcaseID
ShellExecute("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe",iPath)
End Function
Function OnSetFocus(P1 as Integer)
   clearFocus()
End Function
```

This used to give data presented in the application. 
The only change after this setup being tested and found ok, the server which the synonym "points to" have gotten SSL disabled.
After SSL disabling, i track the query in SQL profiler, and I see the query is being made: 
SELECT id FROM vContosoCcase WHERE Refno='58333' and Subcase=0

Why is the result not presented in the application anymore?